# BIG Binary column - PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql, migration, blob

I've got the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE gorfs.inode_segments
(
  st_ino "gorfs"."ino_t" NOT NULL, -- Inode number the segment belongs to. alongside segment_index, it forms the table's primary key to ensure uniqueness per relevant scope
  segment_index "gorfs"."pathname_component" NOT NULL, -- See st_no's column description for further details. The meaning of this column varies based on the host inode type:...
  st_ino_target "gorfs"."ino_t", -- Target inode number. Meaningful for directory inode segments (objects in the directory)
  full_path "gorfs"."absolute_pathname", -- Exploded absolute canonical path for quick lookups. Meaningful only for directory inode segments (objects in the directory)
  segment_data "bytea", -- Actual data segment. Meaningful only for S_IFLNK and S_IFREG....
  CONSTRAINT pk_inode_segments PRIMARY KEY ("st_ino", "segment_index"),
  CONSTRAINT fk_host_inode_must_exist FOREIGN KEY (st_ino)
      REFERENCES gorfs.inodes (st_ino) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_target_inode_must_exist FOREIGN KEY (st_ino_target)
      REFERENCES gorfs.inodes (st_ino) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT uc_no_duplicate_full_paths UNIQUE ("full_path"),
  CONSTRAINT cc_only_root_can_be_its_own_parent CHECK ("st_ino_target" IS NULL OR "st_ino"::bigint <> "st_ino_target"::bigint OR "st_ino"::bigint = 2)
)
```

The column "segment_data" has all the attachments from the customers, like photos, documents, audio, etc.

To improve the performance, we'll be migrating all the data from the segment_data column to a NFS server.

- Full database size: 2 TB
- Using PostgreSQL 9.2
- Table gorfs.inode_segments size: 1698 GB (**Command: SELECT
  pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('gorfs.inode_segments'));**)
- Basically we'll be using: **UPDATE gorfs.inode_segments SET segment_data = NULL WHERE batch_number = 0**
- We won't be migrating all the data on the segment_data column by once, it will be done gradually (over few weeks).

**Question:**

Just by setting "NULL" into that column, will I get free space on the database? Will I have to run any command such VACUUM/VACUUM FULL/ANALYZE/PG_DUMP?

Comment: What's `batch_number`  in UPDATE statement?

Comment: @shx - It's just a number ( 0 or 1 ) So we're able to know if the migration has been successfully applied into the NFS server. So after that we can delete the binary from DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL's MVCC is used over-writing mechanism,  which is roughly mentioned to [this document](http://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-plus-edb-blog/amit-kapila/well-known-databases-use-different-approaches-mvcc) , so all updated rows are **inserted** into the table. Thus, you cannot get free space.  On the contrary, the table size is temporarily increased.

(Even though autovacuum feature works  very efficiently,) I think you have to do `VACUUM FULL` in order to certainly remove dead rows(tuples) and dead pages after updating. That way (do UPDATE SET NULL and VACUUM FULL), the size of the table will be small.